# point color dependent on string column value

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot simple 2D point graph with dots either red or green, where color is determined by third, string column. This one doesn't compile:

```
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:3 with points lc rgbcolor (stringcolumn(4) eq "B" ? "green" : "red")
```

complaining that :

```
stringcolumn() called from invalid context
```

Data looks like this:

```
1,2,"A"
2,3,"A"
3,1,"B"
4,2,"A"
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning a linetype number to each colour, then evaluating column 3 into one of these numbers. Eg:

```
set linetype 1 lc 'green'
set linetype 2 lc 'red'
plot "data.txt" using 1:2:(stringcolumn(3) eq "B"?1:2) with points lc variable
```

Note, your data columns must be separated by whitespace not commas.